# How to correct store LPTSTR in map

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I need to store values from registry in map. I have such code:

```
    map<int, LPTSTR> mymap;

    for (i = 0, retCode = ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++)
    {
        cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
        achValue[0] = '\0';
        retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i,
            achValue,
            &cchValue,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);

        if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            DWORD lpData = cbMaxValueData;
            buffer[0] = '\0';
            LONG dwRes = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, achValue, 0, NULL, buffer, &lpData);

            LPTSTR val = (TCHAR*)buffer;
            MessageBox(NULL, val, L"VALUE", MB_OK);

            auto r = mymap.insert(pair<int, LPTSTR>(i, val));

            for (map<int, LPTSTR>::const_iterator it = mymap.begin(); it != mymap.end(); it++)
            {
                wchar_t szMessage2[1300];
                if (SUCCEEDED(StringCchPrintf(szMessage2, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage2), L"+ %d : %s\n", it->first, it->second)))
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL, szMessage2, L"MAP", MB_OK);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to correct save val to map? Right now all keys have the same value (latest).

Comment: Either `map<int, std::string> mymap;` or `map<int, std::wstring> mymap;`  depending on whether UNICODE is defined.

Comment: `LPTSTR` is a pointer. It points to the beginning of `buffer`. Since you keep reusing the same buffer for future insertions, you simply insert the same pointer over and over again which points to a buffer containing the last value placed in it.

Comment: Given that you're passing wide strings to `MessageBox`, get rid of `TCHAR` and use wide strings. `TCHAR`'s compatibility hasn't really been useful for new code for a number of years, and you evidently don't need it if your code compiles with the wide strings in it. All of the `TCHAR` stuff in the code is only serving to obfuscate it, and for no benefit because undefining `UNICODE` will cause compilation errors.

Comment: @RichardCritten: If the rest of the code is `TCHAR` based (which this example is), you can use `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` to match, instead of using `std::string` or `std::wstring` directly

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a single buffer that you are reusing during enumeration, and you are storing just a pointer to that buffer into your `map`.  So every entry will be pointing at the same physical memory, which contains the last piece of data written to it.

You need to store *copies* of the enumerated string data into your `map`.  Use `std::string`/`std::wstring` for that, eg:

```
using tstring = basic_string<TCHAR>;

map<int, tstring> mymap;

for (i = 0, retCode = ERROR_SUCCESS; i < cValues; i++)
{
    cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

    retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i,
        achValue,
        &cchValue,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD dwData = cbMaxValueData;
        DWORD dwType = 0;

        LONG dwRes = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, achValue, 0, &dwType, buffer, &dwData);
        if (dwRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            switch (dwType)
            {
                case REG_SZ:
                case REG_MULTI_SZ:
                case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
                {
                    tstring val((LPTSTR)buffer, dwData / sizeof(TCHAR));
                    //MessageBox(NULL, val.c_str(), TEXT("VALUE"), MB_OK);
                    mymap.insert(make_pair(i, val));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (auto &value: mymap)
{
    TCHAR szMessage2[1300];
    if (SUCCEEDED(StringCchPrintf(szMessage2, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage2), TEXT("+ %d : %s\n"), value.first, value.second.c_str())))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, szMessage2, TEXT("MAP"), MB_OK);
    }
}
```

However, since you are clearly compiling with `UNICODE` enabled, you shouldn't be using `TCHAR` at all:

```
map<int, wstring> mymap;

for (i = 0, retCode = ERROR_SUCCESS; i < cValues; i++)
{
    cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

    retCode = RegEnumValueW(hKey, i,
        achValue,
        &cchValue,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        DWORD dwData = cbMaxValueData;
        DWORD dwType = 0;

        LONG dwRes = RegQueryValueExW(hKey, achValue, 0, &dwType, buffer, &dwData);
        if (dwRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            switch (dwType)
            {
                case REG_SZ:
                case REG_MULTI_SZ:
                case REG_EXPAND_SZ:
                {
                    wstring val((LPWSTR)buffer, dwData / sizeof(WCHAR));
                    //MessageBoxW(NULL, val.c_str(), L"VALUE", MB_OK);
                    mymap.insert(make_pair(i, val));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for (auto &value: mymap)
{
    WCHAR szMessage2[1300];
    if (SUCCEEDED(StringCchPrintfW(szMessage2, ARRAYSIZE(szMessage2), L"+ %d : %s\n", value.first, value.second.c_str())))
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL, szMessage2, L"MAP", MB_OK);
    }
}
```